# I am trying to pass the Reset Token link to ejs engine but when the mail sent the anchor tag doesn't show the href attribute

Tags: node.js, ejs, viewengine

I am using this syntax in ejs engine to send a clickable link to the email but it's not working. href attribute is not showing anything. But the anchor tag has the value like this

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
<a href="<%=link%>" target="_blank"><%=link%></a>


localhost:3000/resetpassword/MEbiDw8CznhS8vwZ8pMK6EaQ4OhDujilPeFlOv6j9BGFKwPQBruJTCEKLgDzDMG3
```

The above should be a clickable link but it's not.